# How to add more elements to specific key in array?

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I am trying to convert xml node into array, i have 3 separated nodes inside parent match node, so i need to convert all them into array.

When i try this code

```
foreach($lineup->away->player as $player){
    $awaysquad .= $player->attributes()->name . '; ';
    $matcharr['name'] = (string)$player->attributes()->name;
    $matcharr['number'] = (int)$player->attributes()->number;
    $matcharr['playerid'] = (int)$player->attributes()->id;

    $yellowcount = count(explode(" ",$player->attributes()->booking));
    if(substr_count($player->attributes()->booking,"YC") == 1){
      $matcharr['yellow'] = (int)$player->attributes()->id;
    }
    elseif((substr_count($player->attributes()->booking,"RC")==1) 
    or ($yellowcount == 3)){
      $matcharr['red'] = (int)$player->attributes()->id;
    }
}
```

and call this matcharr by:

```
print_r($matcharr);
```

There is just last element for each index/array, i want to get all players from lineup tag.

So print_r prints this:

> Array ( [goal] => 2456166 [name] => Luís Leal [number] => 9 [playerid]
>   => 2474225 [yellow] => 2486288 [subin] => 2353344 [subout] => 0 [minute] => NA )

for each match tag, but i need to get 22 players for each match.

Here is more detailed code:

```
foreach($week->match as $match){
                              $matcharr = array();  
                              //var_dump($match);
                              $fixid = 0;
                              if($match->attributes()->id == 0 || $match->attributes()->id == ''){
                                  if($match->attributes()->alternate_id == 0 || $match->attributes()->id == ''){
                                      $fixid = $match->attributes()->alternate_id_2;
                                  }
                                  else{
                                      $fixid = $match->attributes()->alternate_id;
                                  }
                              }
                              else{
                                  $fixid = $match->attributes()->id;
                              }
                              $dbdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($match->attributes()->date));
                              $dbtime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($match->attributes()->time));
                              //if($dbdate == date('Y-m-d')){
                              echo $dbdate . ' ' . date("Y-m-d");
                              $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($dbdate . $dbtime));
                              $fcountry = $this->filterCountries($results->attributes()->country);  

                              $stadium = $match->attributes()->venue;
                              $city = $match->attributes()->venue_city;
                              //echo $fcountry;
                              //$home = $match->home->attributes()->name;
                              //$away = $match->away->attributes()->name;
                              $home = '';
                              $away = '';
                              $homeid = 0;
                              $awayid = 0;
                              $hgoals = 0;
                              $agoals = 0;
                              if($match->home){
                              $home = $this->getMap($fcountry,$match->home->attributes()->name);
                              $away = $this->getMap($fcountry,$match->away->attributes()->name);
                              $homeid = $this->filterTeams($fcountry,$match->home->attributes()->id);
                              $awayid = $this->filterTeams($fcountry,$match->away->attributes()->id);   

                              $hgoals = $match->home->attributes()->score;
                              $agoals = $match->away->attributes()->score;
                              }

                              $eventname = $home . ' - ' . $away;

                              $halftimehomegoals = 0;
                              $halftimeawaygoals = 0;
                              if($match->halftime->attributes()->score != NULL){
                                  $halftime = explode("-",$match->halftime->attributes()->score);
                                  $halftimehomegoals = (int)$halftime[0];
                                  if(array_key_exists(1,$halftime)){
                                      $halftimeawaygoals = (int)$halftime[1];
                                  }
                              }   
                              $homescore = '';
                              $awayscore = '';
                              if($match->goals->goal != NULL){
                                foreach($match->goals->goal as $goal){
                                    if($goal->attributes()->team == 'home'){
                                       $homescore .= $goal->attributes()->minute.': '.
                                       $goal->attributes()->player.'; ';
                                       $matcharr['goal'] = (int)$goal->attributes()->playerid;
                                    }
                                    elseif($goal->attributes()->team == 'away'){
                                       $awayscore .= $goal->attributes()->player.'; ';
                                       $matcharr['goal'] = (int)$goal->attributes()->playerid;
                                    }
                                }
                              }
                              $homesquad = '';
                              $awaysquad = '';
                              if($match->lineups != NULL){
                                foreach($match->lineups as $lineup){
                                    if($lineup->home->player != NULL){
                                      foreach($lineup->home->player as $player){
                                          $homesquad .= $player->attributes()->name . '; ';
                                          $matcharr['name'] = (string)$player->attributes()->name;
                                          $matcharr['number'] = (int)$player->attributes()->number;
                                          $matcharr['playerid'] = (int)$player->attributes()->id;

                                          $yellowcount = count(explode(" ",$player->attributes()->booking));
                                          if(substr_count($player->attributes()->booking,"YC") == 1){
                                              $matcharr['yellow'] = (int)$player->attributes()->id;
                                          }
                                          elseif((substr_count($player->attributes()->booking,"RC")==1) 
                                          or ($yellowcount == 3)){
                                              $matcharr['red'] = (int)$player->attributes()->id;
                                          }
                                      }
                                    }
                                    if($lineup->away->player != NULL){
                                      foreach($lineup->away->player as $player){
                                          $awaysquad .= $player->attributes()->name . '; ';
                                            $matcharr['name'] = (string)$player->attributes()->name;
                                            $matcharr['number'] = (int)$player->attributes()->number;
                                            $matcharr['playerid'] = (int)$player->attributes()->id;

                                            $yellowcount = count(explode(" ",$player->attributes()->booking));
                                            if(substr_count($player->attributes()->booking,"YC") == 1){
                                                $matcharr['yellow'] = (int)$player->attributes()->id;
                                            }
                                            elseif((substr_count($player->attributes()->booking,"RC")==1) 
                                            or ($yellowcount == 3)){
                                                $matcharr['red'] = (int)$player->attributes()->id;
                                            }
                                      }
                                    }
                                }
                              }

                              $homesub = '';
                              $awaysub = '';
                              if($match->substitutions != NULL){
                                  foreach($match->substitutions as $subs){
                                      if($subs->home->substitution != NULL){
                                          foreach($subs->home->substitution as $sub){
                                              $homesub .= $sub->attributes()->minute."' in: ".
                                              $sub->attributes()->player_in_name . '; ' . ' out: ' .
                                              $sub->attributes()->player_out_name . '; ';
                                              $matcharr['subin'] = (int)$sub->attributes()->player_in_id;
                                              $matcharr['subout'] = (int)$sub->attributes()->player_out_id;
                                              $matcharr['minute'] = (string)$sub->attributes()->minute;
                                          }
                                      }
                                      if($subs->away->substitution != NULL){
                                          foreach($subs->away->substitution as $sub){
                                              $awaysub .= $sub->attributes()->minute."' in: ".
                                              $sub->attributes()->player_in_name . '; ' .
                                              $sub->attributes()->player_out_name . '; ';
                                              $matcharr['subin'] = (int)$sub->attributes()->player_in_id;
                                              $matcharr['subout'] = (int)$sub->attributes()->player_out_id;
                                              $matcharr['minute'] = (string)$sub->attributes()->minute;
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                          echo $leaguename . ' ' . $leagueid . ' ' . $fixid . ' ' . $eventname.'<br>';
                          print_r($matcharr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some counter variable before storing it in array like below

```
$element_count = 0;//Counter variable
foreach ($lineup->away->player as $player) {
    $awaysquad .= $player->attributes()->name . '; ';
    $matcharr[$element_count]['name'] = (string)$player->attributes()->name;
    $matcharr[$element_count]['number'] = (int)$player->attributes()->number;
    $matcharr[$element_count]['playerid'] = (int)$player->attributes()->id;

    $yellowcount = count(explode(" ", $player->attributes()->booking));
    if (substr_count($player->attributes()->booking, "YC") == 1) {
        $matcharr[$element_count]['yellow'] = (int)$player->attributes()->id;
    }
    elseif ((substr_count($player->attributes()->booking, "RC") == 1) or ($yellowcount == 3)) {
        $matcharr[$element_count]['red'] = (int)$player->attributes()->id;
    }
    $element_count++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I rarely use multidimensional arrays, i see now purpose. Marked as answer and problem is solved.